# I can't get the ToggleSwitch control to appear in my Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I can't get the ToggleSwitch control to appear in my Windows Phone app. The code I'm trying to use is:

`<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="ToggleSwitch" Height="111" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,397,0,0" Name="toggleSwitch1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" />`

or

```
<controls:ToggleSwitch Header="Test">
  <controls:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </controls:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
</controls:ToggleSwitch>
```

Neither of which work, and I can't figure out why. It's a C# app that I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to b e a Silverlight app for this to work. Not sure why. I just used a checkbox instead.